# How does __is_const(_Tp) in LLVM's header work?

Tags: c++, templates, built-in

While going through some of the type traits, I was searching how does `std::is_const<type_name>` work. According to the definition in it is

```
#if __has_builtin(__is_const)

template <class _Tp>
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_const : _BoolConstant<__is_const(_Tp)> { };

// ...

#else
// "normal" type trait
#endif
```

I know it's a compiler builtin, but was wondering on a high level as to how it's implemented?

Comment: The implementation is compiler-specific. The compiler has all info of the expression to determine whether all subexpressions contain constants and constexpr calls only. Exactly what are you interested in?

Comment: The fact that it is builtin usually implies that the implementation is in the compiler code itself.  The compiler has more type information during compilation than your code will at runtime.  Ideally, any emitted code does not have to resort to using "Run-Time Type Information" (RTTI) in order to perform certain tasks since types are a language construct and not something the CPU understands.  This is one of those examples.  The compiler can make this determination at compile-time, so it does.

Comment: I was assuming most implementation would be almost the same. I tried searching the LLVM project for the same, couldn't find anything that was helpful. (I'm using clang++)

Comment: Now I'm curious... let me download the source and take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's implemented via an X macro that populates a map of type `llvm::SmallDenseMap<IdentifierInfo *, tok::TokenKind>`.

From `clang/lib/Parse/ParseExpr.cpp`:

```cpp
#define RTT_JOIN(X,Y) X##Y
#define REVERTIBLE_TYPE_TRAIT(Name)                         \
          RevertibleTypeTraits[PP.getIdentifierInfo(#Name)] \
            = RTT_JOIN(tok::kw_,Name)

// ...
          REVERTIBLE_TYPE_TRAIT(__is_const);
// ...

#define TRANSFORM_TYPE_TRAIT_DEF(_, Trait)                                     \
  REVERTIBLE_TYPE_TRAIT(RTT_JOIN(__, Trait));
#include "clang/Basic/TransformTypeTraits.def"
#undef REVERTIBLE_TYPE_TRAIT
#undef RTT_JOIN
```

... and then when parsing your code, the `RevertibleTypeTraits` map is consulted:

```cpp
        // If we find that this is in fact the name of a type trait,
        // update the token kind in place and parse again to treat it as
        // the appropriate kind of type trait.
        llvm::SmallDenseMap<IdentifierInfo *, tok::TokenKind>::iterator Known
          = RevertibleTypeTraits.find(II);
        if (Known != RevertibleTypeTraits.end()) {
          Tok.setKind(Known->second);
          return ParseCastExpression(ParseKind, isAddressOfOperand,
                                     NotCastExpr, isTypeCast,
                                     isVectorLiteral, NotPrimaryExpression);
        }
      }
      // ... and a lot more
```

This is internal compiler details. It'll likely look very different when looking inside another compiler's code.

Comment: There's more to this story (I just went down the rabbit hole) this recursive call ends up in `Sema::ActOnTypeTrait`, which calls `EvaluateBooleanTypeTrait` -> `Sema::EvaluateUnaryTypeTrait`, which finally ends up in a call to [`return T.isConstQualified()`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/lib/Sema/SemaExprCXX.cpp#L5128-L5129). The AST ends up containing a node with a true or false value, annotated with its origin.

Comment: @Botje Yes, there's a lot going on in there and I decided to stay _"on a high level"_ as requested. I hope this answer will be a good entry point for OP in case a deep dive is wanted :-)

Comment: Got the high level overview;) A follow up is, does __is_const get replace with a bool as a sub-task during compilation or does everything happen at once?

Comment: The call to `__is_const` is replaced by a true or false node/value at parse time. Up to you if you call that "at once" or "a subtask" .

Comment: @SreepathyJayanand You may want to take a look at the big `switch` in the `ExprResult Parser::ParseCastExpression(...)` function (which calls itself recursively in many branches). It's interesting because you see trace of many of the fundamental language details in there.

Comment: Got it; I guess not all builtins work the same as I thought. Eg. __builtin_popcount() which would have a different mechanism. Not asking what's the difference since it's out of the scope of this thread :)

Comment: `__builtin_popcount` translates to a custom arithmetic operation node that the optimizer is free to specialize for the target CPU and/or calculate at compile time.